# Update com Case When necessita de where?

Tags: sql, sql-update, case

```
UPDATE bethadba.FOFILHOS

SET CPF = CASE

WHEN CODI_EMP = 61  AND I_EMPREGADOS = 156  AND i_filhos = 1 THEN '00551366133'
WHEN CODI_EMP = 57  AND I_EMPREGADOS = 290  AND i_filhos = 1 THEN '00636170993'
WHEN CODI_EMP = 61  AND I_EMPREGADOS = 333  AND i_filhos = 2 THEN '01056262958'

END

COMMIT
```

Desenvolvi este SQL para inserir alguns números de CPF no cadastro de alguns dependentes, até onde sei, não é necessário colocar o WHERE pois dentro do WHEN já especifica onde deve atualizar as linhas.

Um colega de trabalho cismou que se executar assim vai dar ruim e bugar todos os dependentes, eu disse para ele que não bugaria.

Alguém sabe me dizer ao certo se tem ou não que ter o WHERE?

Banco: Sybase SQL Anywhere 16.

Answer (score 5):

Considerando uma tabela genérica,qual é a diferença entre

`Update tabela  set campo= case when id=1 then 'abc' end`

e

`Update set campo='abc' where id=1`

?

Em termos de resultado da operação, nenhum. As duas estruturas de código vão atualizar `campo` quando o `id` for igual à 1.

Em termos de performance, a estrutura com `case` é muito mais lenta que a estrutura com `where`.

Um `update` vai primeiro criar um conjunto de registros usando como critério a expressão definida no `where`, antes de proceder à atualização propriamente dita. Um `update` sem `where` aplica a alteração sobre todos os registros da tabela.

Veja um exemplo de 5000 linhas no PostgreSQL funcionando no SQL Fiddle
[Exemplo 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/decba/3)

```
update tabela set campo=555 where id =1000;
```

Como plano de execução você pode ver:

```
QUERY PLAN
Update on tabela (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=14)
-> Index Scan using tabela_pkey on tabela (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=14)
Index Cond: (id = 1000)
```

Agora com o `case`,

[Exemplo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/decba/5)

```
update tabela set campo=case when  id =1000 then 555 end;
```

Plano de execução:

```
QUERY PLAN
Update on tabela (cost=0.00..85.50 rows=5000 width=14)
-> Seq Scan on tabela (cost=0.00..85.50 rows=5000 width=14)
```

Note que no primeiro caso foi usado um Index Scan (busca usando o índice ) e no segundo caso é feito um Seq Scan (busca sequencial).

Podemos também notar que que no primeiro caso a query é aplicada sobre 1 registro `(rows=1)` , enquanto a segunda é sobre 5000 registros `(rows=5000)`.

Outro fator é o **perigo** executar uma atualização indevida.

Talvez não seja o seu caso, mas só para explicar o porquê essa técnica é perigosa, imagine esse situação:

[Exemplo 3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/decba/7)

```
update tabela set campo=case when  id =1000 then 555 else 0 end;
```

Parabéns! Você atualizou com sucesso o id 1000 e de brinde você ganhou a atualização dos outros 4999 registros com o valor zero.

Comment: minha dúvida foi esclarecida pelos exemplos 1 e 2.. eu acreditava que seria esse o ponto, ficou 100% claro agora. Boa resposta ;)

Answer (score 3):

A principio não irá ter nenhum impacto, a não ser que existam outros **FOFILHOS** com aquelas condições. Mas se o **CODI_EMP** é utilzado como **ID**, faça esse **UPDATE** utilizando o **WHERE**, geralmente utilizamos **WHEN** para atualizar mais de uma linha e pelo que vi você quer atingir  aquelas 3 apenas, portanto faça um **WHERE** para cada linha.

Comment: Deixei 3 apenas pelo exemplo, mas na verdade são mais de 100 CPF's...

Comment: Entendi! Mas ainda sim, eu utilizaria o WHERE caso o CODI_EMP seja o ID dos dependentes.

UPDATE bethadba.FOFILHOS SET CPF = '00551366133' WHERE CODI_EMP = 61;

Assim me parece mais simple, boa sorte!